# Replacing part of code base with akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have a function which downloads a given webpage :

```
  def getContent(link: String) = {
      scala.io.Source.fromURL(link).mkString
  }
```

getContent is called from within a single threaded app. I'm planning to replace the getContent function with an Akka implementation :

This is what I'm moving towards replacing getContent with :

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Actor._
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.contrib.throttle._
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit._
import scala.concurrent.duration.{ Duration, FiniteDuration }

class HTTPAkkaActorSystem extends Actor {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {

    val greeter = context.actorOf(Props(new ContentReceiver), "greeter")

    greeter ! ContentReceiver.URLMessage("test")

  }

  def receive = {
    case ContentReceiver.URLContent(content) => println("content is " + content);
  }

  object ContentReceiver {

    case class URLMessage(url: String)
    case class URLContent(content: String)

  }

  class ContentReceiver extends Actor {

    def receive = {
      case ContentReceiver.URLMessage(url) => {
        println("accessing and returning content");
        sender ! ContentReceiver.URLContent("this is the content")
      }

    }
  }

}

object GetContentDriver {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("HTTPAkkaActorSystem")
    val ac = system.actorOf(Props[HTTPAkkaActorSystem])
  }

}
```

So I plan to insert `scala.io.Source.fromURL(link).mkString` into `receive` of `Actor ContentReceiver` . The issue I'm discovering is that since `getContent` is run as part of main Thread and is not using Akka then how do I return the content from `receive` of `Actor ContentReceiver` to `getContent` ? `getContent` is utilized in other parts of the app and so cannot re-write it. Reason I tried this approach is that `getContent` is a potential bottleneck as it is going over network so akka seems like a nice fit for this. Only other option I can think of is to add the content created by actor to a queue that can be accessed from anywhere in the app.

Comment: There are lots of nice asynchronous HTTP clients in Scala (e.g. [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html), [Finagle](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/)). It seems like what you want here is a `String => Future[String]`, and that's easy to integrate into an actor-based application if you decide you want to go that route down the line—it's probably not enough of a reason to introduce actors on its own.

Comment: Exactly.  `getContent` is going to have to return a `Future[String]` for this to be asynchronous, which means changing the existing callers of `getContent`.  Actors won't solve that problem (and are probably inappropriate for this problem anyways).

Comment: @Travis Brown using a global synchronized Map which stores the content each actor receives will mean that the content is downloaded asynchronously? I do accept sharing global state within a Map like this is not idiomatic

Comment: How would that make anything asynchronous in this situation?

Comment: @Ryan is the downloading of the content not asynchronous as it's contained within an actor ?

Comment: A global synchronized Map being used by Actors would make unicorns cry

Comment: Yes, putting it in an actor makes it asynchronous but it is by no means the only way, and in this case it would be a silly way.